# I want to setup stripe so a user can pay and register in one step. How do I access the paymentlink metadata for a customer.subscription.created event

Tags: stripe-payments

I want to setup stripe so a user can pay for a susbscription and it will automatically register them through our system in one step after an event is fired. I am trying to send the user registration data in the metadata of the paymentlink. I'd like to retrieve that data when a customer.subscription.created event occurs.  The metadata does not seem to travel with that event. The docs say that the paymentlink metadata will be included in the checkout session, but the checkout session event is sent when checkout is complete whether or not it succeeded.  Is there a way to get the metadata from the customer.subscription.created event?  I'm using php.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now Stripe doesn't copy over the `metadata` of the PaymentLink or CheckoutSession to the Subscription that is created - you have two options:

1. When you receive the `customer.subscription.created` event you can retrieve the associated Checkout Session and check its metadata by passing in the Subscription ID to the List all Checkout Sessions [endpoint](https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/list#list_checkout_sessions-subscription)
2. You can switch over to using CheckoutSessions, which have an additional parameter called `subscription_data.metadata` that you can set during [creation](https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/create#create_checkout_session-subscription_data-metadata). This isn't a parameter that's available with PaymentLinks and it allows you to set separately `metadata` that will be set on the created Subscription.

Comment: Thanks so much. I was able to get it to work with option 1.   I spent two days fumbling on this. Thanks again for the help and choices.